# Install php7.0-sybase inside docker php:7.0-apache-stretch

Tags: docker, debian-stretch, php-7.0

On my container (FROM php:7.0-apache-stretch)

```
apt update
apt install php7.0-sybase
```

Result :

```
E: Package 'php7.0-sybase' has no installation candidate
```

File /etc/apt/sources.list :

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main
```

How to install this package?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below that worked with me on `php:5.6-apache` to connect to Sybase:

I use provided script `docker-php-ext-configure` and `docker-php-ext-install` in [Official PHP image](https://hub.docker.com/_/php) to install `sybase_ct` extensions.

And use [FreeTDS](https://www.freetds.org/) to connect to Sybase server.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y  unixodbc unixodbc-dev freetds-dev freetds-bin tdsodbc \
    && docker-php-ext-configure sybase_ct --with-sybase-ct=/usr \
    && docker-php-ext-install sybase_ct

COPY ./src/ /var/www/html/
COPY ./odbcinst.ini /etc/
COPY ./freetds.conf /home/
RUN cat /home/freetds.conf >> /etc/freetds/freetds.conf
```

Configured `odbcinst.ini` file to copy to `/etc/odbcinst.ini`

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = TDS driver (Sybase/MS SQL)
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
```

Configured `freetds.conf` file to add in `/etc/freetds/freetds.conf`

```
# Sybase Server
[ServerName]
    host = example.com
    port = 5000
    tds version = 5.0
```